# Magento 1.7 Cart "Edit Item Parameters" becomes "Tab Item Parameters"

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, bug, product-edit

I've found a bug in my Magento cart. Whenever there is a configurable item in the cart, the text that should read "Edit" instead says "Tab". This only occurs for configurable products - simple products show the appropriate "Edit" text.

I've already taken a look at app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml and the code there looks proper:

```
 <td class="a-center">
        <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit item parameters') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
        <?php endif ?>
    </td>
```

[image]

Any ideas what might be going on here, or where to start with diagnosis?

(Below is the entire default.phtml)

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><?php endif;?><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?></a><?php endif;?></td>
    <td>
        <h2 class="product-name">
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </h2>
        <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
            <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
            <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">* <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
            <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </td>
    <td class="a-center">
        <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit item parameters') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
        <?php endif ?>
    </td>
    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
    <td class="a-center">
        <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getMoveFromCartUrl($_item->getId()); ?>" class="link-wishlist use-ajax"><?php echo $this->__('Move'); ?></a>
        <?php endif ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
        <td class="a-right"<?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?> colspan="2"<?php endif; ?>>
            <span class="cart-price">
                <span class="cart-msrp-unit"><?php echo $this->__('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>
                <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                <a id="<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>" href="#" class="map-help-link"><?php echo $this->__("What's this?"); ?></a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    Catalog.Map.addHelpLink($('<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>'), "<?php echo $this->__("What's this?") ?>");
                </script>
            </span>
        </td>
    <?php else: ?>

        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td class="a-right">
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>


            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td>
            <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="a-center">
        <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
    </td>
    <?php if (($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) && !$_item->getNoSubtotal()): ?>
    <td class="a-right">
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart-msrp-subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </span>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) && !$_item->getNoSubtotal()): ?>
    <td>
        <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getSubtotalInclTax($_item); ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart-msrp-subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </span>


        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="a-center"><a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?>" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Very odd. The code you've posted does look to be correct and isn't causing the issue. Certainly looks like an issue caused by your theme though. Could you post more of your item phtml?

Comment: why you want tab

Comment: @performadigital I've added the code to my original post

Comment: @AmitBera I don't want tab, but that's what it is currently displaying. I'd prefer that it said "Edit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you click the `Tab` link? If you are transfered to the edit page it's probably just a translation error. You could change the link text with the `Inline translate` tool:

`Admin->System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer -- Traslate Inline->Enable for Frontend->YES`

Regards...

Comment: It will not change every instance of the word `Tab`, but it will change every link `Tab` in the Mage_Catalog scope like in the picture: [link](http://prntscr.com/7n3msq). If that is a problem, than you shouldn't do that.

Item description is a custom text and it is not influenced by the Inline translation tool.